# Grounded for careless review tasks: how long is "a couple of days"?

Tags: support, review, review-suspension

I lost the ability to do review tasks because I failed too many tests.  I was told to "come back in a couple of days".  I've learned my lesson and am keen to make amends by reviewing again, but more carefully.

**How long is "a couple of days"?**  It's been 48 hours.

Comment: related: [Review ban progressive system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256234/839601)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If my math is right, you're about 2.5 hours shy of 48 hours.

Mind you, your SO profile tells me that the ban lifts in 2 hours... but I don't have the code in front of me right now to figure out if it's just bad rounding on display or not. Either way, your review ban should clear up sometime in the next 2-3 hours.